# Best choice: StateObject or EnvironmentObject?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have one SwiftUI View which contains multiple Views:

```
ViewA()
ViewB()
Viewc()
```

All three views do some modification to an object. Should this object be passed to the views as an EnvironmentObject or should they be ObservedObject with the source of truth (StateObject) in the main View?

Trying to understand what the best approach is.

Edit:
All the views edit and modify the object and the other views need to update when it is modified.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the object that manages the lifetime of the model structs then `@EnvironmentObject` is the standard choice. If it's just a fetcher/loader object that is using Combine and the lifetime is tied to the view using `@StateObject` then `@ObservedObject` is fine. If you were passing this object through layers of View structs that don't need the object then you could also use `@EnvironmentObject` to avoid passing it all the way through as let properties.

Comment: I don't quite understand the response. The object does not manage the lifetime of the Views but contains some information about their states. The views need to stay updated with the latest information about the object.

Comment: In SwiftUI we don't store view state in objects, we use the View struct's @State for that.

Comment: I am aware. It's because the state of all three views are dependent on this common object. So they need to share state. And for this purpose I wanted to know which would be better Environment or StateObject

Comment: You do that with a @ State struct in a parent View and you pass it to another View by declaring a let property if you only need to read or @ Binding if you need to write. We don't use objects for this, Swift and SwiftUI are designed around value types like structs not objects.

Comment: It's large so I don't want to pass by value. I would much rather pass by reference.

Comment: Since it's Swift that doesn't matter. However, usually you only pass along the view structs the bits of data it needs.

Comment: So what if I have an app with multiple views, like a TabView, then NavigationViews for each tab, and detail  views in the NavigationViews and I need to make a network call to fetch data when the app launches. Can I do this with a ObservedObject in my TabView without the network call gets terminated when navigating deeper in the view-hierarchy? Will the redrawing of the view cause a new network call to refetch the data? Would a StateObject be a better solution, or even an EnvironmentObject even if I don’t need access to it from every other views (but probable some of them)?